# RegEx for passing punctuation

Tags: regex

I am using:

```
(.*) CO\s?[\(.*\)|\[.*\]|\{.*\}|''.*''|".*"](.*)
```

to represent

```
3M CO 'A'(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY).
```

However, the first Single quotation mark cannot be covered by the regex code. Could you please tell me why?

```
s/(.*) CO\s?[\(.*\)|\[.*\]|\{.*\}|''.*''|".*"](.*)/$1 CO $2
```

I expect to get:

```
3M CO 'A'(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)
```

but I get

```
3M CO A'(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)
```

Comment: If you hover over the `regex` tag you will notice that it asks you to give more information (i.e. the language/program you are using the regex in).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that here we wish to design an expression and match our inputs, part by part, such as:

```
(.+?)\s+CO\s+(['"].+?['"])([(\[{]).+?([)\]}])
```

We have added extra boundaries, which can be reduced, if not desired.

We are having three main capturing groups:

```
(.+?) # anything before Co;
(['"].+?['"]) # the quotation part; and
([(\[{]).+?([)\]}]) # inside various brackets included those, which we can escape, if required.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/TwJDWM/1/)

#### Demo

This snippet just shows that how the capturing groups work:

```js
const regex = /(.+?)\s+CO\s+(['"].+?['"])([(\[{]).+?([)\]}])/mg;
const str = `3M CO 'A'(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)
3M CO 'A'[MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY]
3M CO 'A'{MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY}
3M CO "A"{MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY}`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TwJDWM/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be expressed to

```
/(.*)\sCO\s?(\(.+\).*|".+".*|'.+'.*|{.+}.*|\[.+\].*)/
```

> `(.*)` First capture group will capture starting group ("3M" in your example)
>
> `\sCO\s` Then looks for a whitespace followed by `CO` followed by a whitespace
>
> `(".+".* etc.)` Second capture group that looks for starting quote or bracket followed by at least one character of anything followed by closing quote, then followed by any number of any character

**Why Original Regex Didn't Work**

In the original regex, `[\(.*\)|\[.*\]|\{.*\}|''.*''|".*"]` can be simplified into `[''.*'']` (for the string you provided). I realize that for other strings, you might want to look for `(.*)` or `[.*]` or `{.*}` or `".*"`, but for the "3M" string, only the `[''.*'']` is relevant so we'll just look at this.

So `[''.*'']` just means: match any character in the list inside `[]`, in any order. In this case, there are three *unique* characters in the list: `'`, `.` and `*` (although you did repeat `'` 3 times).  So it matched the first `'`. But since this match is outside your capture group `()`, this first `'` is not included in your capture group response.

So the next match with `(.*)` matches everything else that comes after the first `'` and includes them in the second matching group, i.e. `A'(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)` without the `'` in front.

Does that make sense?

**Demo**

If you wanted to ensure the format includes `'A'` or `[A]` or `"A"` or `{A}` or `(A)`, then this is what you want:

```js
let regex = /(.*)\sCO\s?(\(.+\)|".+".*|'.+'.*|{.+}.*|\[.+\].*)/;

[pattern, match1, match2] = "3M CO 'A'(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)".match(regex);
console.log(match1 + " CO " + match2);
//3M CO 'A'(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)

[pattern, match1, match2] = '3M CO (A)(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)'.match(regex);
console.log(match1 + " CO " + match2);
//3M CO (A)(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)

[pattern, match1, match2] = '3M CO "A"(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)'.match(regex);
console.log(match1 + " CO " + match2);
//3M CO "A"(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)

[pattern, match1, match2] = "3M CO [A](MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)".match(regex);
console.log(match1 + " CO " + match2);
//3M CO [A](MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)

[pattern, match1, match2] = "3M CO {A}(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)".match(regex);
console.log(match1 + " CO " + match2);
//3M CO {A}(MINNESOTA MINING AND MANUFACTURING COMPANY)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `'` does not match because in the second capturing group because you use a character class which can be written as `CO\s?[(.*)|[\]{}'"]` and then it will match `CO '`

So your pattern actually looks like:

```
(.*) CO\s?[.*()|[\]{}'"](.*)
^         ^             ^
group 1   Char class    group 2
```

What you might do to get those matching in 2 groups is to use:

```
(.*?)CO\s?((?:(['"]).*?\3|\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]|\{.*?\}).*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(.*?)` Capturing group 1, match any char except newline non greedy
- `CO\s?` Match CO and optional whitespace char
- `(` Capturing group 2

  - `(?:` Non capturing group, match any of the options

    - `(['"]).*?\3` Match ' or " and use a backreference to what is captured
    - `|` Or
    - `\(.*?\)` Match `(`....`)`
    - `|` Or
    - `\[.*?\]` Match `[`....`]`
    - `|` Or
    - `\{.*?\}` Match `{`....`}`
  - `)` Close non capturing group
  - `.*` Match any char until the end of the string
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NwVWKU/1)

Note that the `.*?` is non greedy to prevent unnecessary backtracking and over matching.